# writeToFile:atomically: method appends to currently exisiting file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, writetofile

It seems like the writeToFile method appends to the currently existing file path as long as the method calls happen during the same application runtime. Is this true?

Are there any other ways to ensure appending to an existing file while an application session is running? I would like the file to be overwritten on a new session.

FYI, I am using an NSMutableDictionary as the receiver to the writeToFile message.

Comment: No. `writeToFile:atomically:` always overwrites any existing file, if any.

Comment: Now this is deprecated.

Comment: What makes up a session? Can a session span app startups?

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya `NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically:` is not deprecated.

Comment: @rmaddy It's a single application and a session is defined to be that instance the app is running until it is deleted/removed from either the background or device.

Comment: @David Then why do you need to write the file at all? If your session starts when the user starts the app or enters the foreground, and the session ends when the user enters the background (or the app is killed), then there is no need to persist the file at all. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I would like to keep a log of everything for reference that happens during that application session

Comment: @David But why write it to a plist file? You have the dictionary in memory. You purge it on session start. What benefit is there to having the plist file at the end of a session? At that point the app isn't running. Or do you store the file in the Documents directory and you access it from iTunes?

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I would like to store the plist file locally to access offline at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure the file is overwritten for each new session, simply delete the file when a new session starts.

To append to a file, you can use an `NSOutputStream` to write the data. Open the file for appending. But if you are writing a plist file from an `NSDictionary`, then this won't work. The better solution would be to load the dictionary at app startup, update it in memory as the apps runs, and write the dictionary to a file when the app enters the background. This assumes your "session" isn't defined by app startups (or background/foreground transitions).

Comment: I am in fact writing a plist file from an NSDictionary. I allocate and initialize the dictionary on app launch and repeatedly add new objects to the dictionary while writing to the same file name. I guess this is why it seems like I am currently appending to the existing file.

Comment: It seems like appending but in reality you are simply replacing the existing file with the new plist representing the updated dictionary. I'm still trying to understand why you keep writing the file at all. It makes no sense given your requirements.

Comment: Ahh, make sense! Is this a bad way to do it?

Comment: Just write the file once when the app enters the background. That's it. From what you have said, there is no reason to keep updating the app while the user is actively using the app in the foreground.